# Why my computer suddenly need such a long time to start uwsim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why my computer suddenly need such a long time to start uwsim? It could start uwsim very fast before. But now it needs over ten minutes. I used rosclean command but it is not helpful. I don't know why.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228213/why-my-computer-suddenly-need-such-a-long-time-to-start-uwsim/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on 2016-03-04**:
btw, my computer did not connect internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> btw, my computer did not connect internet

Hi,

That is the reason why. Resource retriever tries to connect to internet. If your internet connection is faulty it takes some time as every 3D model loaded calls the resource retriever. I suggest solving connection problems or just disable it.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0